# How to import appContext.xml with Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an annotation-based `spring-boot` app and want to import the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appContext.xml`.

The following does not work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath*:appContext.xml")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

But if I copy the `appContext.xml` to `src/main/resources` it works as expected.

How can I make the `WEB-INF` folder work?

Comment: `@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/appContext.xml")`. `WEB-INF` isn't on the classpath. However as you are using Spring Boot it could be that the WEB-INF is ignored.

Comment: @membersound Why you can't move your appContext within the classpath?

Comment: I can, but I'd prefer the standardlayout so that it is placed in WEB-INF.

Comment: If you are planning on running the application as a jar then you should not place resources in `src/main/WEB-INF`. Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with the docs posted by @geoand, I found the following:

> Do not use the src/main/webapp folder if your application will be
>   packaged as a jar. Although this folder is a common standard, it will
>   only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most
>   build tools if you generate a jar.

So it is clear I should indeed copy my context file to `src/main/resources` instead.